# How to put automatic tags/alias to the fields of a select MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, tags, alias

In my database MYSQL I have enough tables and fields (and these fields have to be this way, at the request of the client). But when I make a select, the "alias" has to be show differently.
Example: Name of field in BBDD: **employeeName**; Name which should appear in my select: **Name**

The problem is that there are many tables and many fields per table ... And if for every select I do, I have to put the aliases to all fields ... I see it impractical.

Is there a way to translate fields automatically? As an automatic alias?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At last. An easy one. No.

Comment: You could create a table with each row containing a table name and column name, and an alias for that column. Then create a stored proc that translates the names and builds a query string with the alias'. Sounds like something that should be done in a language like PHP or similar, which is where it should be instead of in SQL.

Comment: Right. My intention was to do it this way. But I did not know how to execute it. I tried to put a function in the alias, passing the name of the field and the table, but had an error that was not allowed:

SELECT employeeName as fn_field_translate ('employeeName', 'employees') FROM employees.